# Bootstrap font sizing for mobile, tablets and PCs

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am writing a small game using bootstrap and want the font size to remain proportionally consistent on a phone, tablet and PC.

```
<h1>Points: {{points}}</h1>
```

The trouble is that the above is much smaller on higher level resolutions and it wrecks the layout I have designed for the game.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Perhaps take a look at http://fittextjs.com/ or http://patrickmarabeas.github.io/ng-FitText.js/ or even using a `font-size` based on the viewwidth `vw`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @ckuijjer, the vw unit works well. As you resize the window, the font size resized in proportion to the size of the window.

```
@media all {
    h1 { font-size: 6vw;}
    h2 { font-size: 5vw;}
    h3 { font-size: 4vw;}
    h4 { font-size: 3vw;}
    h5 { font-size: 2vw;}
    h6 { font-size: 1vw;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use %. This makes the font size depend on the screen size. Media queries might help to find time this..